# Trying to prompt user to set permissions on app launch in AndroidManifest

Tags: android

Okay, so in my `AndroidManifest.xml` file, I'm trying to set my `permissions` such that when the App launches, the user is asked to allow `Location` + `Storage` permissions.

I'm working off the `BluetoothLeGatt` example, and I used the `uses-permission-sdk-23` tags to do it.

For reference, here's my code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <!-- Min/target SDK versions (<uses-sdk>) managed by build.gradle -->

    <!-- Declare this required feature if you want to make the app available to BLE-capable
    devices only.  If you want to make your app available to devices that don't support BLE,
    you should omit this in the manifest.  Instead, determine BLE capability by using
    PackageManager.hasSystemFeature(FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE) -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <activity android:name=".DeviceScanActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DeviceControlActivity"/>
        <service android:name=".BluetoothLeService" android:enabled="true"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

**step 1 :- add  permission that you want in manifiest file like this**

```
 android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
 android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
```

**step 2 : ask runtime permission like this**

```
String permission = android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(SearchCityClass.this, permission)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.
                checkSelfPermission(SearchCityClass.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SearchCityClass.this, new String[]
                    {permission}, PERMISSION_GPS_CODE);

        }
```

**step 3: handle permission result like this**

```
 @Override
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                   @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
if (requestCode == PERMISSION_GPS_CODE) {
    if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


        Toast.makeText(this, location_permission_granted_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {

        Toast.makeText(this, location_permission_not_granted_msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where do I put the code for Step 2?

I was thinking onCreate(), but I wanted to verify?

Comment: yes your can ask permission in on create method ex. step 2

Comment: @Nazoog ask me in case of any query

Comment: When I tried copying this exact function (changing ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION for BLUETOOTH), ActivityCompat, SearchCityClass, PackageManager, and PERMISSION_GPS_CODE all don't work.

I'm not trying to access fine location anyways :(

Comment: @Nazoog  PERMISSION_GPS_CODE is a random number pass any number in deckare int PERMISSION_GPS_CODE=1

Answer (score 1):

uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

In MainActivity add the following

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {

    //We already have permission. Write your function call over hear

} else {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        // Here we are asking for permission

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);


    } else {

//If the app is running for second time, then we already have 
permission. You can write your function here, if we already have 
permission.//



    }

}
```

do same for memory storage..

Comment: You dont need a special code to handle permissions below 23. It will automatically return true for check permission

Comment: I tried just copying that code into my onCreate, but ContextCompat, PackageManager, and ActivityCompat were all showing up red as if they couldn't be recognized.

Is there something I need to make sure I include at the top of my .java file?